# how to use variable value from c # web application in a package SSIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I am developing a web application in c #. Net.
What I need is to import records from sql to an access db. I have no problems with the import, but I need to filter the records imported by a variable that is in the web application.
I need to use as a filter variable "username"
variable in c#

```
string username = (string) HttpContext.Current.Session ["Username"];
```

How I can send and use this variable "username" to SSIS package to do the following filter?

```
SELECT ID, address
FROM my_table
WHERE (username = @username)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you starting your SSIS package? Where do you need to be able to do this filtering (data flow or an Execute SQL Task)? Is this an OLE or ADO.NET connection manager that you will be using?

Comment: Starting like this: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spExportaNormalizado", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); In SSIS use data flow. Connection is OLE DB. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the dtexec to start the package, the .NET library, SQL Agent or some other mechanism to make it run?

Comment: Use xp_cmdshell to make it run...

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have your proc `spExportaNormalizado` set to accept parameters.